# i want to creat a table on sql server with vb.net where the values are in a datagridview but the update doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, datagridview

i'm trying to creat a table on my sql server from a datagridview 
here's my code

```
Form2.ShowDialog()
    Dim grid = DirectCast(Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0), DataGridView)
    Static Dim header As New ArrayList
    Dim sql As String
    Dim values As String = ""
    connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=ABDELOUAHED;Initial Catalog=table_creances;integrated security=true")
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In grid.Columns
        column.HeaderText = column.HeaderText.Replace(" ", "_")
        column.HeaderText = column.HeaderText.Replace("é", "e")
        column.HeaderText = column.HeaderText.Replace("'", "")
        header.Add(column.HeaderText)
    Next
    sql = "CREATE TABLE " & Form2.TextBox1.Text & "(" & header(0) & " int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," & header(1) & " int," & header(2) & " int," & header(3) & " real," & header(4) & " real," & header(5) & " date," & header(6) & " date," & header(7) & " real," & header(8) & " int)"
    Try
        Dim Mycommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Mycommand.Connection.Open()
        Mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Mycommand.Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
Try
        cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        changes = ds.GetChanges()
        If changes IsNot Nothing Then
            adapter.Update(changes)
        End If
        MsgBox("Changes Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

the table is created but it contains no value, the update part doesn't work
any help would be very appreciated

Comment: You haven't shown how you build `adapter` nor `ds` so it is difficult to say, but I would bet that the dataset rows are all in an unchanged state. Does `changes` have rows or not?

Comment: i'm new to vb.net i made my code copying from different sites on internet so i don't really understand it , but the update part work  when i want to update changes (another button)